# Laravel 5.1 GuzzleHttp Client error: 404 when using mailgun

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using the Mailgun service when sending mail with Laravel.  However, i've set this up today and it's just stopped working.  I have entered all the correct info in `.env`, `config/services.php` and `config/mail.php`.  However i'm still getting the below error:

```
ClientException in Middleware.php line 69: 
Client error: 404
```

It looks like the domain is not getting passed through somehow, even though in my `config/services.php` file I have:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('mydomain.com'),
    'secret' => env('<my-mailgun-key>'),
],
```

I have hidden the above credentials for safety, but in my real application they are the proper values.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hade the same problem as you and solved it by removing the env() call.
Thats because env will return the value of the env variable in the first argument (not the value of the argument) and otherwise return the second argument.

So:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'mydomain.com',
    'secret' => '<my-mailgun-key>',
],
```

Try that.

Comment: This is a bad workaround. If the OP is mis-using the `env()` function, the solution is not to avoid using it, but rather using it as intended.

Answer (score 6):

I was having a very similar 404 issue and tried the solution mentioned by Rogério. I thought I was doing it right, but gave it a try anyway. But misuse of the env() function wasn't my problem.

I set the config/services.php back to look like so:

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN',''),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET',''),
    ],
```

This will provide empty strings if the values named MAILGUN_DOMAIN and MAILGUN_SECRET are not found in the .env file. Then, in my .env file, I included the **API Base URL** and **API Key** from the Mailgun domain information page. So the .env looked something like this:

```
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox123abc.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-123456abcdef
```

The values were passing along as they should, but still 404. Looking at [How do I start sending email](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/202464990-How-do-I-start-sending-email-) documentation at Mailgun, I saw that their API URL included "messages" on the end - which I tried manually adding to the .env setting:

```
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox123abc.mailgun.org/messages
```

That didn't work either, but lead me to look more carefully at the stack trace spit out by Laravel. That's when I noticed that the URL it was trying to connect with was:

> https://api.mailgun.net/v3**https://api.mailgun.net/v3**/sandbox123abc.mailgun.org/messages/messages.mime

Ah-ha! Using Mailgun's **Base API URL** was incorrect! That was made obvious by the repetition of the "https://api.mailgun.net/v3" portion. So the aptly named MAILGUN_*DOMAIN* setting really just needed to be:

```
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox123abc.mailgun.org
```

Seems obvious now, but I spent way too much time figuring it out. Thought I'd put it out there in case anyone else happened to miss that detail